# Fetching Images from Wikipedia API except .svg extension

Tags: php, api, wikipedia-api

I am trying to extract images from the Wikipedia API in my PHP page. But I am getting some unnecessary images in .svg extension. Is there a way i can avoid it .svg extension or just include .jpg extensions from the api request? I could see a variable called mediatype, but it was not working.

I am using the following api request url:

```
 https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&redirects=1&action=query&titles=Basilica%20Cistern&prop=images&format=json&imlimit=15
```

And the response i am getting is below:

```
{
  "continue": {
    "imcontinue": "1365761|Peacock-eyed_column_in_the_Basilica_Cistern_in_Istanbul,Turkey,January_20,2014.jpg ",
    "continue ": " || "
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "1365761": {
        "pageid": 1365761,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Basilica Cistern",
        "images": [{
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:20131203 Istanbul 269.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Archaeological site icon (red).svg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Basilica Cistern.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Basilica Cistern Constantinople 2007.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Basilica Cistern Constantinople 2007 011.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Basilica cistern Art.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Carp at the Basilica Cistern, Istanbul 2007.JPG"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Commons-logo.svg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Head of Medusa, Basilica Cistern, Constantinople 01.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Head of Medusa, Basilica Cistern, Constantinople 02.jpg"
          },
          {
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Location map Istanbul.png"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
function getResults($json){

$results = array();

$json_array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_array['query']['pages'] as $page){
    if(count($page['images']) > 0){
        foreach($page['images'] as $image){

            $title = str_replace(" ", "_", $image["title"]);
            $imageinfourl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=query&titles=".$title."&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json";
            $imageinfo = curl($imageinfourl);
            $iamge_array = json_decode($imageinfo, true);
            $image_pages = $iamge_array["query"]["pages"];


            foreach($image_pages as $a){

                $results[] = $a["imageinfo"][0]["url"];
            }
        }
    }
}

return $results;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see anything in the API. I thought maybe you could use the `imimages` parameter but it's only useful for matching the entire `title`, eg

```
...&imimages=File%3A20131203%20Istanbul%20269.jpg
```

What you can do is filter the results

```
// snip
if(count($page['images']) > 0) {
    $jpgs = array_filter($page['images'], function($img) {
        return strtolower(pathinfo($img['title'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) === 'jpg';
    });

    foreach($jpgs as $image) {
        // and continue
```

---

Alternately, just check the extension in your `foreach` loop

```
foreach($page['images'] as $image) {
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($img['title'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) !== 'jpg') {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: I am using the below php code to get the images:    foreach($image_pages as $a){                    
$results[] = $a["imageinfo"][0]["url"];
}.. Am new to php, can u pls tell me how to include your code in this?

Comment: @Sanju sorry, that doesn't look anything like the JSON in your question. You'll have to show some actual code if you want more help

Comment: @Sanju I've updated my answer to fit it in with your code

Comment: The second option worked out for me. Thank you so much Phil. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can filter by image type when using the search API (which gets data from ElasticSearch which can efficiently filter by all kinds of things) but not with other APIs like `images` or `pageimage` (which get the list of images directly from the database and have a very limited number of indexes to work with).